# Генерация UML Activity/Sequence Diagram из Java кода

Tags: java, uml, моделирование

Для создания детализированной документации нужно построить диаграммы процессов, происходящих в Java-коде. Желтально в UML нотации, но можно и в любой другой. Какой инструмент для этого использовать?

В интернете есть куча ссылок на софт и события, произошедшие более 10 лет назад, когда был обширный хайп вокруг тематики UML. Хорошо бы иметь какой-нибудь современный инструмент, который прошел сквозь все эти десятилетия и просто работает.

Соответствующие плагины для IntelliJ IDEA, например, протухли совершенно, с датами релиза за 2007 год. Насколько понимаю, современный полу-динамический Java код уже совершенно нельзя анализировать без знания работы фреймворков, что обычно умеют делать только IDE. То есть предполагается, что данный софт должен быть плагином для IntelliJ IDEA, в крайнем случае Eclipse, или быть standalone - но при этом фантастически умным, либо просто использовать какие-то методы runtime-анализа.

Важно подчеркнуть: инструмент построения диаграмм классов не нужен совершенно (для этого можно использовать просто плагин Code Iris для IntelliJ IDEA), нужен инструмент парсинга-моделирования последствий самого императивного кода на Java.

Comment: После того как разобрался с Enterprise Architect другие тулы не перевариваются. Но он дорогой. Сейчас вынуждено использую Visio, благо компания поставляет, добавив туда фигуры UML 2.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [ObjectAid UML Explorer](http://www.objectaid.com/), он позволяет довольно просто строить диаграммы для существующих классов и позволяет строить диаграммы последовательностей (Sequence Diagram) и диаграммы классов (Class Diagram), и его последнее обновление датировано ноябрем 2015г. К сожалению плагин только для Eclipse.